# How do I take a function from a user as a test variable throughout the testing with pytest?

Tags: python, testing, structure, pytest

I am new to `pytest` and I have been struggling to implement this part of my own library: Taking a function from a user and save that function as a variable so that that could be used and accessed throughout the testing. I am trying to pass a function that I defined in `playground.py`(pretending I am a random user) to the `sortoy.py`.  I heard using `global_variable` for this is not recommended. Is there any recommended way of doing it?

My whole Library structure looks like below:

```
my_library
-my_library
    -__init__.py
    -sortoy.py
-LICENSE
-playground.py --> This is where I am testing my code
-README.md
-setup.py
```

This is the code for `playground.py`

```py
import my_library.sortoy

# The defined array
def bubbleSort(arr): 
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] : 
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j] 
    return arr

my_library.sortoy.sort_function(bubbleSort) # Taking user defined function
```

This is the code for `sortoy.py`

```py
import pytest

small_cases = [([1], [1]), ([2, 1], [1, 2]), ([2, 2], [2, 2])]

@pytest.fixture # I was trying to use this for taking user function (It does not work however).
def sort_function(f):
    return f

# The test I am trying to run
@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_case, sorted", small_cases)
def test_one_element(sort_function, test_case, sorted):
    assert sort_function(test_case) == sorted

# Script version of pytest so that I could run the test_case above once I have got the user-defined function.
pytest.main(["-v"])
```

For the information, the library I am trying to implement is to test the user-defined function for users when they pass in the `sort_function` they have created (like sorting). When `my_library.sortoy.sort_function(bubblesort)` is called, this library is supposed to execute the testings(`test_one_element()` in this case) automatically and show on console if it has failed or passed the tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are two main ways you can solve the problem you're trying to solve, as it seems somewhat like a "framework" problem.

I see what you're trying to do with `my_library.sortoy.sort_function(bubbleSort)` but it won't work the way you want because it's "backwards" in terms of which file is doing which thing.

1. Force the user to name their function something specific which you can then import easily
2. Create a decorator such that the user is able to specify what their sort function is

**Use a specific name**

In this case you modify

```
@pytest.fixture # I was trying to use this for taking user function (It does not work however).
def sort_function(f):
    return f
```

to look more like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def sort_function():
    from ..playground import bubbleSort as f
    return f
```

**Create a decorator**

The basic gist is that you want the user to write something like this:

```
from mylibrary import sortfunc

@sortfunc
def bubbleSort(arr): 
    n = len(arr)
    for i in range(n): 
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1] : 
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j] 
    return arr
```

Then you do something with the functions that are registered to your library as it were which you can then use in your pytest files.
`mylibrary.py`

```
SORT_FUNCS = {}

def sortfunc(f):
    global SORT_FUNCS
    SORT_FUNCS[f.__name__] = f
    return f
```

Then from your test framework file you can do something like:

```
@pytest.fixture
def sort_functions():
    from mylibrary import SORT_FUNCS
    return SORT_FUNCS # returns the dict of names, function handles
```

In this case you would probably use this `sort_functions` as something you can parametrize as well since it's entirely possible that a user could decorate more than one function.

**Bonus**: The pytest way

You could also tell people to use a particular module name and then import and search through that module for anything with "sort" in the name and assume that everything from that module with "sort" in the name is a sort function.

```
@pytest.fixture
def sort_functions():
    import ..playground
    sort_funcs = []
    for attr in dir(playgound):
        if "sort" in attr.lower():
            sort_funcs.append(getattr(playground, attr))
    return sort_funcs
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answers! The second way of using decorators sounds good to me since it would allow users to keep their own function name. However, I heard using global variable is not such a good behaviour. Would it still be fine? And for the test framework file (my_library.py) Can't I access `SORT_FUNCTION` without importing it? Is test framework file you mentioned somewhere else? Thank you!